# How to get same size in every direction while Extrude Along Normal?

Tags: extrude

How do I get same size in every direction while extruding along normals? Dont know why but size is not same and its kinda disoriented(Some side is getting fatter).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Offset Even` [Extrude](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html?highlight=extrude) function